# Regex accepting names and numbers only

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm looking for something will accept names, salutations, and numbers. Things like Mr., O'Henry, and Bobby-Lee should also be accepted. So besides a period, an apostrophe, a hyphen, letters, and numbers, nothing should work. Not even whitespace. Help is much appreciated!

Comment: Searching regexlib a bit. Couldn't come up with anything quickly, so asked here. Personally, don't know nearly enough to write my own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not even whitespace? I know people whose first name has two parts spelled with a space rather than a hyphen (English versions of Vietnamese and Chinese names).

http://regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html and
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions will tell you all you need to know to do something simple like this, but anyway:

```
var someString = "a string to test";

var namePattern = /[^A-Za-z\d.'-]/;

if (namePattern.test(someString)) {
   // contained invalid characters, do something
}

// Or you can say /[^A-Za-z\d.'-]/.test(someString) - no need to assign
// the regex to a variable if you're not using reusing it.
```

A regular expression with `[^...]` will match any character other than the ones following the `^`. `\d` is for numeric digit.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I am already splitting the text the user inputs by spaces, in order to be able to make separate calls per word they enter. So just in case they put two spaces or something, I don't want to accept whitespace. Thanks again.